# Grammar: "I'll try AND help them"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, tenses, conjunctions

There are tens of questions here on EL&U about the grammaticality of the *try and do something* construction and its merits compared with the unremarkable *try to do something* collocation.

However, this question is not related to those in any way. This question is about the grammatical constraints on the use of the *try and do something* construction.

This morning whilst on a coffee break I realised that the *try and do something* construction, henceforth referred to as *tryand* for short, is not a ready replacement for *try to do something*. So far these are the grammatical constraints that I have noticed:

1. *Tryand* is restricted to the present tense only:

   - I try and visit once a week.
   - *I tried and visited once a week. (ungrammatical with this meaning)
   - *I tried and visit once a week. (ungrammatical with this meaning)

I put the two ungrammatical versions there, because it is not clear whether the second verb in the *tryand* construction is usually present tense or plain form (aka an infinitive).

2. When occurring in the present tense, *tryand* cannot be used in the third person singular:

   - I try and visit them.
   - You (all) try and visit them.
   - *He tries and visit them. (ungrammatical)
   - *She tries and visits them. (ungrammatical)
   - They try and visit them.
3. *Tryand* is useable as the complement of other present tense verbs without the third person restriction, or any past time reference restriction:

   - You can try and visit them
   - He can try and visit them
   - He would try and visit them
4. There is also no restriction on either the third person or the use of the past simple if the auxiliary *do* is used:

   - She does try and visit every week.
   - She did try and visit them as often as possible though.
5. This does not work with the perfect auxiliary *have* where there seems to be a bar on past time reference:

   - *She has tried and visit them as often as possible (odd or ungrammatical)
   - *She has tried and visited them as often as possible (ungrammatical with this meaning)

So, what I have drawn from this is that perhaps *tryand* cannot be used in any construction where the second verb would have to be inflected.

My questions are the following:

- Are there any further restrictions on the use of *tryand* which I have missed?
- When the verb *try* in the *tryand* construction is present tense, is the second verb also present tense or is it a plain form of the verb  (an infinitive)?
- Why exactly does *tryand* have these restrictions?

Answers to any or all of the questions above would be welcome.

Comment: I think _tryand_ is evolving in the direction of _goand_ and _comeand_, which have fewer restrictions: _He went and did it; He's gone and done it; He goes and does it_. The restrictions of _tryand_ seem similar to those of _goVP_ and _comeVP_, where no conjunction or complementizer occurs: *_He went did it,_ *_He's gone done it._ *_He goes do/does it_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, very interesting.  That might help explain something else too. It seems that  *tryandget* (as opposed to general *tryand*)  patterns like a tiny bit more like *comeand* and *goand*, perhaps. *He tries and gets her to ....* (as mentioned to me by Peter Shor, which was troubling me), and also *Try get her to ...*, but not **He tries gets her to*

Comment: That sounds right. I wrote a paper a while back ([handout here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/leftovershandout.pdf)) about the evolution of an idiomatic syntactic construction (_remain to_, as in the idiom _It remains to be seen_); this kind of partial overlap of restrictions reminds me of that.

Comment: A very interesting question and discussion. *Oxford Dictionaries* acknowledged some of these properties in its entry for [*try*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/try): 'The construction *try and* is grammatically odd, however, in that it cannot be inflected for tense (e.g. sentences like *she tried and fix it* or *they are trying and renew their visa* are not acceptable, while their equivalents *she tried to fix it* or *they are trying to renew their visa* undoubtedly are). For this reason *try and* is best regarded as a fixed idiom used only in its infinitive and imperative form.'

Comment: I am not sure the restriction on the appearance with auxiliary *have* is really valid. We have such attested examples as [*has tried and succeeded*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kQsAAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22has%20tried%20and%22&pg=PA461#v=onepage&q=%22has%20tried%20and%22&f=false) and [*has tried and thought of*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2RpcAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22has%20tried%20and%22&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q=%22has%20tried%20and%22&f=false). Granted, the examples are very dated, but to me at least, they sound natural. (I take *(have) tried and failed* to be a fixed expression, so it doesn't count.)

Comment: I've just amended my answer with a discussion from CGEL. They say the second verb is always in plain form, which can be seen by testing with ***be***: *We always try and be* /* *are helpful.*

Comment: @linguisticturn Nice data from CamGEL there!!

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100129/go-shut-the-door-or-go-and-shut-the-door-ame-bre-difference).

Answer (score 4):

1. You may add interaction with **negation** to your list of restrictions.
2. The second verb is in the plain form, as is evident when we test with ***be***: *We always try and be*/**are helpful.*

**Negation**

One property to add to your list of restrictions is interaction with **negation.**

There is an extensive discussion of *try and* in [*Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=opdWDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA920&dq=%22try%20and%22%20inflect%20acceptable&pg=PA920#v=onepage&q=%22try%20and%22%20inflect%20acceptable&f=false), where, in addition to some of the restrictions you have already listed, they also note the following:

> A negative may precede *try and,* but if a negative follows *try, to* is used:
>
> *... when you are on your moorings, **don't try and** get into her*—Peter Heaton, Cruising, 1952
> ***Not to try and** keep either a diary or careful income tax records* —And More by Andy Rooney, 1982
> ***Try not to** take her out shopping* —nurse quoted in McCall's, March 1971

**The second verb is in the plain form**

Here is the relevant discussion from [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) (p. 1302), which includes some other interesting observations.

(b) *Try/be sure and* V

[32]            PLAIN FORM + PLAIN FORM          PLAIN PRESENT + PLAIN FORM
           i  a.  ***Try** and not **be** so touchy.*            b.  *We always **try** and **do** our best.*                 [*try*]
          ii  a.  ***Be** sure and **lock** up.*                     b.  [not possible]                                            [*be sure*]

This is very different, semantically and syntactically, from the ordinary use of *and*. Note first that, unlike the clausal coordination *We always try and we do our best,* [ib] does not entail that we do our best. Secondly, this idiomatic construction is syntactically restricted so that and must immediately follow the lexical base *try*; this means that there can be no inflectional suffix and no adjuncts: *She always tries and does her best* and *We try hard and do our best* can only be ordinary coordinations. There are two forms that consist simply of the lexical base: the plain form, as in [ia], and the plain present tense, as in [ib]. But the verb following *and* is always a plain form, as is evident when we test with ***be***: *We always try and be*/**are helpful.* In spite of the *and*, therefore, this construction is subordinative, not coordinative: *and* introduces a non-finite complement of *try*. *And* can be replaced by the infinitival marker *to*, *and* being slightly more informal than *to*. *Be sure* works in the same way as *try*, except that the lexical base of ***be*** is only the plain form, so this time there is no plain present tense matching [ib]: *We are always sure and do our best* is not possible as an example of this construction (and unlikely as an ordinary coordination). Because the construction is subordinative, the across the board restriction does not apply: *This is something [that you must **try**/**be sure** and remedy].*

**Other constructions in which *and* replaces a possible *to***

Relevant to your discussion with John Lawler, *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* also says that

> Quite a few commentators lump *try and* with other constructions in which *and* replaces a possible *to*. *Go and* is the oldest of these, dating back to the 13th century. It has always been respectable in speech and casual writing... Unlike *try and, go and* can be inflected, as in these constructions: *... and he **went and** sat on a stone* —Kay Cicellis, *Encounter,* March 1955... *Come and* is also old, and equally respectable... *Be sure and* is also frequently encountered.
>
> There are a few other verbs that turn up with *and* where *to* could have been used:
> *He didn't have to **stop and** think about his answer*—Elmer Davis, *But We Were Born Free,* 1954
> *And you can tell your daddy that someday I'll be President of this country. You **watch and** see*  —Lyndon B. Johnson, quoted in Sam Houston Johnson,
> *My Brother Lyndon,* 1970
> *If you want to write, **start and** write down your thoughts* —Leacock 1943

They also mention *take and* (*Homer was courting a second time to get him a good wife and a home-keeper for his children, when he **took and** fell off the church-house roof* —Maristan Chapman, T*he Happy Mountain,* 1928)

[*The Columbia Guide to Standard American English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l9g3BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA246&dq=%22try%20and%22%20inflect%20acceptable&pg=PA246#v=onepage&q=%22try%20and%22&f=false) also mentions *up and* (*He **up(ped) and** punched me in the nose*).

Comment: I don't think the negation will work there as a special comment on this construction though. It is just a fact of English that the adverb *not* always comes before any non-finite forms that it negates. So it can come before the verb *try* if *try* is non-finite.  It can only come before *to* if there's a *to* infinitive there. So there does not seem to be any special restriction there. there's no surprises, as far as I can see.

Comment: Nice addition from CamGEL, pity I can only upvote you once!